# Error: Could not find or load main class org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect

Tags: java, hibernate

When I run my program I get this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect

I have checked all the jar files required are in place. Please help. I guess there is problem with the hibernate configuration file. Find the configuration file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">batch</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">batch</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>
        <mapping resource="galaxe.model.Network" /> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

In configuration you need to mention for DB2390 as below
 property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect"

if you use oracle, it will be different
 property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect">

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: then please try the 
value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"